# What are all the properties available on a Component object in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

`import ItemPanel from '../Panel/ItemPanel.svelte';`

If I log `console.log(ItemPanel)`, I get the class definition:

```
class ItemPanel extends SvelteComponentDev {
        constructor(options) {
            super(options);

            init(
                this,
                options
...
```

But if I `console.log(ItemPanel.name)`, I simply get `"ItemPanel"` returned to me.

I use the panel's name in a modal component that receives components to open, and this is how I've been IDing them for special functionality. But then I realized that I lose that functionality on production build because I'm `tensor()`ing and that changes the component's name in production. I'm hoping to log all properties to see if there's one that sticks between both dev and production mode.

Comment: `Object.keys(ItemPanel)`.

Comment: Yeah! Tried that, returned [].

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a Svelte-specific question, though of course I could be mistaken.

Answering what you actually asked, you can get the properties of an object (including a function object) via [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) (for the ones with string names) and [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) (for the ones with Symbol names). (In contrast, [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) only gives you a subset of what `getOwnPropertyNames` gives you: the names of own *enumerable* properties with string names. [`getOwnPropertyNames` includes non-enumerable ones.]) To get inherited properties, use `Object.getPrototypeOf` and then use the first two functions again. Rinse, repeat until you reach `Object.prototype`.

But getting to your underlying requirement:

`ItemPanel` in your code is a constructor function. Functions get their names by how they're defined. A constructor function created via a named `class` declaration or expression (yours looks like a declaration) gets its name from the name given for the `class`. The `name` property of a function gives the name of the function.

If you're minifying the code in some way such that `name` is no longer what you're looking for, and you need some similar unique identifier, you can add one using a [`static` field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features):

```
class ItemPanel extends SvelteComponentDev {
    static id = "ItemPanel";
    // ...
}
```

Of course, that means repeating yourself.

But stepping back a step:

> I use the panel's name in a modal component that receives components to open...

In that situation I'd use the actual function rather than its name.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation! I'll hang around to see if any Svelte Guys know of anything, but indeed this showed me the props I needed and sadly none are available to help. We don't define classes as you've exampled there with the `static id` assignment, so what I'll do (now that I can justify it) is just pass the component's name itself when I build the modal. Thank you!